# How can I overlay a background pattern on PNG image visible part?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way I could add a background pattern to a `png` images visible part? I need to add a triangle with a pattern on top of it, but so far the pure `css` solutions for this haven't worked for me so is there a way to do this?

Basically I need a triangle with dimensions of `width: 45px; height: 23px;` overlayed with a pattern.

Like the one over here: http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/ pointing downwards and a pattern on top of it.

Comment: something like  http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment by @Fabrizio, you can use the **clip-path** CSS property like so:

```
.triangle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red url(URL-TO-OVERLAY-PATTERN) scroll no-repeat 0 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(47% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(47% 100%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}
```

This produces a downwards pointing triangle like so...

[image]

but you'll need to adjust the percentages to achieve the exact triangle shape you need.